# Does Ansible microsoft.ad always require domain_username and domain_password?

Tags: ansible

I have a simple ansible playbook

```yaml
- name: manage ad objects
  hosts: win
  tasks:
    - name: Create AD group
      microsoft.ad.group:
        name: Test Group4
        domain_username: "{{ domain_username }}"
        domain_password: "{{ domain_password }}"
        scope: domainlocal

    - name: Create an OU
      microsoft.ad.ou:
        domain_username: "{{ domain_username }}"
        domain_password: "{{ domain_password }}"
        name: MyLabTest
```

The only way I can get `microsoft.ad` working is by supplying domain_username and domain_password. Is there a way the playbook can be simplified so domain_username and domain_password is not required and ansible uses the ansible_user credentials by default?

```yaml
- name: manage ad objects
  hosts: win
  tasks:
    - name: Create AD group
      microsoft.ad.group:
        name: Test Group4
        scope: domainlocal

    - name: Create an OU
      microsoft.ad.ou:
        name: MyLabTest
```

According to the notes in https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/microsoft/ad/group_module.html "If running on a server that is not a Domain Controller, credential delegation through CredSSP or Kerberos with delegation must be used or the domain_username, domain_password must be set." - Unfortunately, I'm unable to run these playbooks directly against a domain controller, and our security team are against a delegation and CredSSP is disabled.

What I was hoping was to use something like become or just tell each of the tasks to use a default credential.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ***Is there a way the playbook can be simplified so `domain_username` and `domain_password` is not required and Ansible uses the `ansible_user` credentials by default?***

According documentation [Module defaults](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_module_defaults.html) and [Connecting to hosts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_inventory.html#connecting-to-hosts-behavioral-inventory-parameters) you may test with

```yaml
- name: manage ad objects
  hosts: win

  module_defaults:
    microsoft.ad.group:
      domain_username: "{{ ansible_user }}"
      domain_password: "{{ ansible_password }}"
    microsoft.ad.ou:
      domain_username: "{{ ansible_user }}"
      domain_password: "{{ ansible_password }}"

  tasks:

  - name: Create AD group
    microsoft.ad.group:
      name: Test Group4
      scope: domainlocal

  - name: Create an OU
    microsoft.ad.ou:
      name: MyLabTest
```

Comment: Ha, you were faster. I wonder if something like `group/microsoft` will work - module defaults for groups is still a preview feature and `microsoft.ad.*` modules are not listed in its documentation.

Comment: It works, ignore my previous deleted comment. Thank you for this :)